# Vue Object isn't returning updated value despite seeing the value updated

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm writing tests for Vue.js and I'm trying to write the test to ensure that when some props are changed for pagination, the resulting values within the component are updated properly.

So when I console.log the component, I see the correctly updated values, but then when I try to literally grab that attribute it gives me the old and outdated value. **Look at rangeList** in the following screenshot to see what I mean:

[image]

Here is my code so that you see how what is generating this output.

```
pagComp.$refs.component.limit = 10;
pagComp.$refs.component.pages = 145;
console.log(pagComp.$refs.component);
console.log('RangList: ' + pagComp.$refs.component.rangeList.length);
```

Here is the code that modifies rangeList:

```
 createListOfRanges() {
   let range = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < this.pages; i++) {
     range.push(i);
   }
   this.rangeList = [];
   while(range.length > 0) {
     this.rangeList.push(range.splice(0, this.rangeLength));
   }
   this.correctLastRange();
 },
```

Finally, there are two places this function is called: when the component is being created, and when the `pages` attribute changes. Here is the watcher:

```
watch: {
 pages(val) {
   this.createListOfRanges();
 }
```

},

Comment: Can you show the code that modifies `rangeList`?

Comment: sure thing! I've updated the question with that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the answers above, however they aren't what the issue was.

The problem was with Vue's lifecycle. I'm not 100% sure why, but when the page and limit variables are changed it takes another moment for the page watcher (shown above) to get executed and update the component. So thus it wouldn't show up in my tests. So what I did was use `nextTick` like so, which fixed the problem.

```
pagVue.limit = 10;  // limit and pages change together every time automatically
pagVue.pages = 145;
Vue.nextTick(() => {
  expect(pagination.rangeList.length).toBe(25);
})
```

Comment: Interesting phenomenon. You might want to ask in the Vuejs github issues form and see if they know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I see some issues with this part of your code:

```js
while(range.length > 0) {
    this.rangeList.push(range.splice(0, this.rangeLength));
}
```

`range.splice(..)` returns an array, which is getting pushed into `this.rangeList`

Forget about that for a minute. Look at the following example:

```js
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x.splice(0, 2)  // result: [1, 2]
```

As you can see above, splice returns an array, not an element. Now, in the same example above:

```js
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [10, 11]
y.push(x.splice(0, 2))
```

Check the value of y. It will be `[10, 11, [1, 2] ]`. It is an array within another array. It does not look very meaningful here. You can do the above `x` and `y` experiments directly in your developer console.

In your case, your `x` happens to be the local `range` array within `createListOfRanges` method, and your `y` is `this.rangeList` that belongs to your Vue component.

Can you check your app logic at around that area, and see if that is really what you want to do?

For debugging Vue.js apps, you also need Vue devtools: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools - it is much better than `console.log()`

Comment: I appreciate your input here, although this part of the code is doing what it should. `range` starts out being created into something like [1,2,3,4,5,6], and then the function uses that to generate something like [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]. That's what is happening so it's all good there.

Answer (score 1):

While @Mani is right on the line of code giving you issues is your push to `rangeList`.

```
createListOfRanges() {
  let range = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < this.pages; i++) {
    range.push(i);
  }

  this.rangeList = [];
  while(range.length > 0) {
    this.rangeList.push(range.splice(0, this.rangeLength));
  }
  this.correctLastRange();
},
```

pushing the result of the splice just makes a single element with all the elements of range in it.

try changing it to

```
this.rangeList.push(range.shift());
```

Though your function could be simplified by pushing the `for(let i = 0; i < this.pages; i++) {` `i` value directly to `rangeList` unless that's a simplification.

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcuzor1w/3/) shows what I'm talking about.